# Create file OLS in Python Statsmodels

Tags: python, pandas

I dont have much knowledge in Python but I have to crack this for an assessment completion,

**Question:**
Run the following code to load the required libraries and create the data set to fit the model.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import pandas as pd 

boston = load_boston()
dataset = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)
dataset['target'] = boston.target

print(dataset.head())
```

I have to perform the following steps to complete this scenario.

For the boston dataset loaded in the above code snippet, perform linear regression.
Use the target variable as the dependent variable.
Use the RM variable as the independent variable.
Fit a single linear regression model using statsmodels package in python.
Import statsmodels packages appropriately in your code.
Upon fitting the model, Identify the coefficients.
Finally print the model summary in your code.
You can write your code using vim app.py .

Press i for insert mode.
Press esc and then :wq to save and quit the editor.

Please help me to understand how to get this completed. Your valuable comments are much appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import pandas as pd 

boston = load_boston()
dataset = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)
dataset['target'] = boston.target

print(dataset.head())

import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

X = dataset["RM"]
y = dataset['target']

X = sm.add_constant(X)

model = smf.OLS(y,X).fit()

predictions = model.predict(X)

print(model.summary())
```

Comment: Thank you, Will try and will update... And for your question the answer is Yes

Comment: Sorry @Nurgle, this didn't work.  After executing the python code `python app.py | tee output.txt.` it didn't go through

Comment: Please let me know if any suggestions for this  ?? @Nurgle

Comment: Hi, sorry busy  these days with work. Tomorrow i am going to run code again because only task which is pending is output.txt. I am also stuck on same error because output is correct and also going to ask my senior. Are you able to clear the quiz after this hand on practice?

Comment: yes i already completed it, if you share ur email id I can send it to u... :) i am pending with only these 2 hands on :(

Comment: i am able to get the exact output which asked in code and also able to write in text file by command 
python app.py >> output.txt. 
but it's not accepting the final result in Hands on.

Comment: yes the same issue for me as well, I can't find any difference in the table generated by the code they provided and what we executed...

Comment: you can contact me on nurglejoker@outlook.com.

Comment: any progress on Hands-On?

Comment: No, Still stuck on same. evening having correct output not able to complete.
you can contact me on email or provide your contact details i will share the output if i get succeeded.

Comment: Hi, are you able to complete the first handon ?
as above code run this time successfully

Comment: What type of Document ?

Do you need steps with screenshot. ?